# gcc compiling and linking

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I created a shared library in this way

```
gcc -I/home/lib 'pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 libxml-2.0' -shared -fPIC -Wl,--export-dynamic file1.c file2.c -o lib.so
```

it works and the library created also works for what I need.
What I want to know is where the compiling and the linking are in this command string, so please explain it to me and tell me a way to divide them in two different commands, just to understand better.
I need to understand this because I can't not explain why this library works, even if this has to be linked to another one that I've never linked to it.

Comment: With the command you show, the frontend-pogram `gcc` calls the compiler and the linker as one unit. Or do you mean that you want to know which command-line options and flags are specific for compilation, for linking, and common to both?

Comment: You do not link anything.

Comment: @P__J__ Shared libraries are linked just like executable programs.

Comment: Yeah, I want to know which command-line options and flags are specific for compilation, for linking and common to both

Comment: The `-Wl,` is the start of the linker command options, which you have `--export-dynamic` as the single linker option. This tell `gcc` to compile the file using the compiler options shown (and those generated from the call to `pkg-config`, then call the linker *With linker options* `,--export-dynamic`. Add `-v` for verbose output, e.g. `gcc -v .....` and you will see all that is put together to compile and link. Unlike a simple assembly program where you compile to object and then simply call `ld` to link to executable, there is a lot more done to link with the C-runtime libs.

Comment: Ok thanks, now what I don't understand is why it works. Let me explain, this is a library I made to add objects in Dia (the Diagram editor). In the ~/home/lib directory that I mentioned before I have what you can find in the lib directory inside Dia sources. In my two .c files I call lot of times extern functions we can find in .c files in lib folder, but I think functions should be only declared but not defined, so why do they work? Last thing, if I try `ldd 'which dia'`, it says it's not an dynamic executable program, so it also cannot import shared library, so where do I take functions?

Comment: `-o` is what makes the linker create a binary executable, so I guess you can say that this is the "linker part".

Comment: Also, depending on where you install the shared libraries you create, you can tell the program to find them there by using the `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/your/lib`. When programs run, they look to a standard library search path. Your libraries are not generally stored there, so you use `-rpath` to tell the executable where to find your libraries in their custom location.

Comment: @Lundin: “-o” does not tell gcc or ld to make an executable. It specifies the name of the output file. It may be used with any operation, such as preprocessing only or compiling only, to specify the name of the output file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command compiles and links in one invocation.

You can split the command into compiling and linking commands:

```
gcc -c -o file1.o -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I/home/lib $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 libxml-2.0) -fPIC file1.c
gcc -c -o file2.o -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I/home/lib $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 libxml-2.0) -fPIC file2.c
gcc -shared -o lib.so file1.o file2.o
```

Answer (score 5):

GCC uses the extensions in the file names to determine what type they are and what to do with them. So the fact that you listed some names ending with “.c” tells GCC to compile them as C code. If you had given only names ending with “.o”, GCC would treat them as object files and would not compile them.

After compiling, GCC by default links to make an executable. The “-shared” switch tells it to make a shared library instead.

To compile only, without linking, you could use the switch “-c” and remove the “-shared” switch, and also remove any of the command arguments or switches that are only used for linking (“-Wl,--export-dynamic” is one, and I do not know whether that pkg-config will produce any link options). Also remove or change the “-o lib.so”, since that sets the name to use for the output file, and it is not what you want for object files that result from compiling only.

To link only, without compiling, you would simply list object files instead of source files and remove the switches affecting compilation (“-I/home/lib”, “-fPIC”, and any produced by pkg-config).

Comment: Now this is a great answer. I didn't know GCC uses extension to distinguish tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The **gcc -c** option is for compile only. However, I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.